# Django allauth urls produce 404

Tags: python-3.x, django-cms, django-allauth

So I'm trying to add all auth to existing DjangoCMS project and ran into this kinda weird issue. I added urls like this:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  # NOQA
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),  # <-- here )
```

But when I go to any url, say mydomain.com/en/account/login/ I get 404. In debug mode Django lists all sorts of patterns it tried to match, and among them - `en/ account/ login/ [name='account_login']`, concluding with

> "The current path, /en/account/login/, didn't match any of these."

Moreover if I add `{% url 'account_login' %}` to a template, it works just fine, producing a link to mydomain.com/en/account/login/ which is still a 404 error. I have no idea where to even start debugging this :( Any suggestions?

Edit:

- the contents of my allauth urls.py https://pastebin.com/PZDH6EDm
- Django version 3.0.7

Comment: Can you please add the urls.py file for allauth and state which Django version you are using?

Comment: @Aiky30 Django 3.0.7 and I pasted allauth urls.py into pastebin

Comment: My apologies, I asked for the urls.py file because I thought allauth was custom, I haven't used it before and didn't know of it's existence. 

Can you please clarify that you followed the following documentation and you have the apps installed in the settings.py file that you require?

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/docs/installation.rst

Answer (score 0):

Replace the url with path:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns[
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),  # NOQA
    path(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    path('account/', include('allauth.urls')),  # <-- here 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Upd: pages do work if I'm not already logged in as admin. Try loging out first